# PHP - Validating oauth_token without making api call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, vbulletin

I'm writing a PHP class for vBulletin for Facebook connect. I need a way of validating an oauth token without making an cURL request to Facebook for validation checks.

It has to perform some string-format validation but cannot be tied to just specific permission oauth tokens ect, has to be fairly 'generic'. Has anyone does this before, and if so, how?

Looking forward to your replies. :)

Comment: Define „validation“ – what exactly do you want to check for …?

Comment: You might want to explain what's the problem, because it sounds like you are looking for the wrong solution...